# How to use fluent Nhibernate components

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to use components in fluent nhibernate and am getting the below error.

*FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.*

Does the code below look right or am I missing something?

Below is the object im ttrying to reuse

```
public class Thickness
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte ThicknessSize { get; set; }
}
```

I have implemented it in my entity class as below

```
public class Liner
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Thickness Thickness { get; set; }
}
```

The map for the entity is

```
public class LinerMap : ClassMap<Liner>
{
    public LinerMap()
    {
        Table("Liner");
        Id(l => l.Id);
        Component(l => l.Thickness);              
    }
}
```

The configuration looks like below

```
   public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {

        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c
                .Server("XXXXX")
                .Database("XXXXX")
                .Username("XXXXXXXXXX")
                .TrustedConnection()))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Liner>())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Thickness>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

I've noticed that the fluent wiki says that this feature doesn't work for automapping hence ive explicitly used the .mapping method, but im not sure if this is enough

Any ideas will be gratefully welcome

GB

Comment: Have you looked at the InnerException (which might have other InnerExceptions)?  There are often clues buried in the stack trace.

Comment: Also, can describe what the Component method does and what namespace it come from. I don't see it listed in the [ClassMap](http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Mapping/ClassMap%601.htm) documentation.

Comment: You lost automapping because you are using a CLASSMAP. You need to use OVERRIDES if you want to get automapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a little digging into the [Component method](https://github.com/nhibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#components) and if your code is attempting to use its capabilities then it needs another parameter. I'm not sure why it would even compile the way it is written but it needs two parameters, a parameter for the reference property and another describing the the mapping for that reference property.

Comment: I'll have a better look at the component method later. I have already been through the fluent wiki, but i'll look again and try later.

Comment: In the end I decided to leave the components and just create distinct entities

Comment: URL has bit rot, the page is now located at https://github.com/nhibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#components (and I can't edit the post to update it in place)